# how do I iteratively add a different number of elements to each item in a list?

Tags: python, list, loops, enumerate

I have a list of elements that occur in order and I'd like to add one at a time to a list.

Desired output:

```
'first_page'
'first_page + second_page'
'first_page + second_page + third_page'
'first_page + second_page + third_page + fourth_page'

...
```

Data structure:
`page_list = ['first_page', 'second_page', 'third_page', 'fourth_page']`

How can I get desired output? Thanks!

So far, I'm able to add the next page to the previous page using this function:

```
new_list = []
for index, elem in enumerate(page_list):
    if(index<(len(page_list)-1)):
        new_list.append(elem + ' + ' + page_list[index+1])
    else:
        new_list.append(elem)
```

which returns:

```
['first_page + second_page',
 'second_page + third_page',
 'third_page + fourth_page',
 'fourth_page']
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `join()` to create a delimited string.

You can use incrementing slices of the original list as the list to slice.

```
page_list = ['first_page', 'second_page', 'third_page', 'fourth_page']
new_list = [' + '.join(page_list[:i]) for i in range(1, len(page_list)+1)]

print(new_list)
```

Or you can keep appending to another list before joining.

```
new_list = []
pages = []
for page in page_list:
    pages.append(page)
    new_list.append(' + '.join(pages)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
pages = []
for index, elem in enumerate(page_list):
    pages.append(page_list[:index + 1])
print(pages)
```

Comment: Would that do in one line? 

    pages = [page_list[:index + 1]for index, elem in enumerate(page_list)]
    print(pages)

Comment: yes you can do it , i test it

Comment: Why use `enumerate()`? The second element `elem` of the tuple it yields is unused.

Comment: "I didn't pay attention, but you can use range if you prefer."

Comment: The enumerate(0 is more advantage over range()

Comment: How is `enumerate()` more advantageous in this context than `range()`, @toyotaSupra? `Enumerate()` is preferred while accessing single elements of a list in a for-loop, certainly. But, this is not what is happening here. The for-loop is accessing a growing remainder of elements from the list over which it is iterating. This solution even fails to produce the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to start with `new_list` containing the first element of `page_list` and iteratively add the last element of `new_list` to successive elements of `page_list`, essentially  having a 'running total' stored as the last element of `new_list`.

This is slightly faster than the other solution as it only does each join once, rather than joining every element of `page_list` for each element of `new_list`.

```
new_list = [page_list[0]] # Initialise new_list with first element of page_list
for elem in page_list[1:]: # For the other elements of page_list
    new_list.append(new_list[-1] + ' + ' + elem) # Add another element of page_list each iteration

print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about to do in one line.

```
pages = [page_list[:index + 1]for index, elem in enumerate(page_list)]
print(pages)
```

Answer (score 0):

So lets break down the problem:

1. We need to iterate over every element in `page_list`
2. For every element we iterate over, we need to iterate over all previous elements before it, and add it to a string in the format `[a] + [b] + [c] + ... [n]`

Because we plan to iterate over each element in the list, but also the ones before it, it is probably wise to use the *index* of the elements, rather than the elements. This means we should probably make use of the `range(start, end)` feature.

To start, we can do

```
page_list = ['first_page', 'second_page', 'third_page', 'fourth_page']

new_list = []

for i in range(0, len(page_list)):
    pass
```

And now we are iterating over the list. However, inside the for loop, we will probably need to iterate over previous entries too:

```
page_list = ['first_page', 'second_page', 'third_page', 'fourth_page']

new_list = []

for i in range(0, len(page_list)):
    for j in range(0, i):
        pass
```

And then we will need a way to build the string - we need to be able to add to the string and handle the case where the string has one and more than one entry:

```
page_list = [...]

# ...

str = ""

if len(str) > 0:
    str += " + "
str += page_list[index]
```

And then we put it all together (I changed something, but I'll leave that as an exercise for you to figure out what was the change from above, and why):

```py
page_list = ['first_page', 'second_page', 'third_page', 'fourth_page']

new_list = []

for i in range(1, len(page_list) + 1):
    str = ""
    for j in range(0, i):
        if len(str) > 0:
            str += " + "
        str += page_list[j]
    new_list.append(str)

print(new_list)
```

It should give:

```
['first_page', 'first_page + second_page', 'first_page + second_page + third_page', 'first_page + second_page + third_page + fourth_page']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
page_list = ['first_page', 'second_page', 'third_page', 'fourth_page']
for i in range(len(page_list)):
    sub = page_list[:i+1]
    sub = ' + '.join(sub)
    print(sub)
    
'''Output:
first_page
first_page + second_page
first_page + second_page + third_page
first_page + second_page + third_page + fourth_page
'''
```